# handling forms in django (beginner question)

Tags: django, django-forms

I am a primarily a PHP guy. How would I handle forms in django? I managed to create a form, model and a view. Now I want to save my data into the database.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
import datetime

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(initial='Your name')
    comment = forms.CharField(initial='You comment')
    commend_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today);
    posted_by = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And my view is like this:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import Template, Context
from mysite.blog.models import Blog         #load a model
from mysite.blog.forms import CommentForm   #load a form


def index(request):
    try:
        blog_posts = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-post_date')[:10]

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()

    except Blog.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('blog/posts.html', locals())
```

Then my template (**blog/posts.html**) is like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Dummy Django Site{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}A sample header{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    {% if blog_posts %}
        {% for post in blog_posts %}
        <b>{{post.title}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{post.post_date}}</b><br/>
        <b>{{post.posted_by}}</b><br/>
        {{post.content}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <h2>A Sample Form</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
    </form>

{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<hr/>
Great footer!
{% endblock %}
```

In PHP, I would put in something in my controller like:

```
//from <form action="http://mysite.com/saveComment" method="POST" >
function saveComment() {
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $data['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];
    $model->save($name);
}
```

How would I do that in Django? What where would I put the code?

Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I would be glad if you send me to a reference / documentation for this.

Comment: The Django documentation is actually quite good - one the best for opensource in my experience! http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: Also, I recommend [Practical Django Projects, 2nd ed.](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430219385).

Comment: The part I am confused about is the actual saving of the POSTed data in views.py. Can anyone give me a quick example using the Comments model above? This is close: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form but it does not show me how to save it into a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need a lot of custom stuff, check out [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/), but [Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/) are sufficient for an awful lot of use cases.

P.S. If you're really doing `Comment`-related stuff, check out the [provided `Comments` app](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingFreeComment) in `django.contrib.comments`.

UPDATE: Instead of defining your views and forms as you have above, use a `ModelForm` instead. This will allow to use code like the following to do the save:

```
# Save a new Comment object from the form's data.
>>> new_comment = my_comment_form.save()
```

The change to your `forms.py` would change the definition of `CommentForm` to something like:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment  # Assumes you've imported your model somewhere
```

UPDATE 2: In general:

- to save a model instance, just invoke `.save()`
- to access `POST` data from a form, use the `cleaned_data` attribute of the `Form` you constructed from the `POST`

Comment: Thank you for this. I am mostly interested in "saving" the actual data in Django. Can you show me in your post how to do that the recommended way saving the data into my "comments" table?

Comment: So many ways to do things. Thank you pointing out ModelForm. I will look into this tomorrow. I have to get some sleep.